# Threads in R sharing changes in values

Tags: r, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am creating threads, But they are not sharing the data between threads. That means what I am updating in one thread I can see the change in other threads . I am using R parallel package. Please help.

Comment: I am creating threads, But they are not sharing the data between threads. That means what I am updating in one thread I **can**  **not** see the change in other threads . I am using R parallel package. Please help.

Comment: I assume you are using parallel::mclapply() - that use _forked_ processes.  R and the parallel package do not parallelize using _threads_.  Since R is a _functional_ language, by design, it does not allow parallel executions to modify each others variables / memory.